# Does an externally driven Foucault pendulum really demonstrate the rotation of the Earth?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, coriolis-effect

There's a [Foucault pendulum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foucault_pendulum) at my school. It's a 105 kg ball suspended from the ceiling with a 20.73 m wire ([source](http://www.etsmtl.ca/nouvelles/2008/Agrandissement-de-l-ETS) in French). There seems to be a driving mechanism on top, where the wire is attached.

Does the fact that it's driven by an external force in any way hinder or augment the effect?

If it *is* possible to drive the pendulum without affecting the demonstration, how does the mechanism accomplish this?

Comment: If they told a worker to pull it back every morning, and it then swung freely for the next 24 hours, that would also be a driving force, just a different type of driving force.

Comment: There are losses in energy, so the pendulum slows down. The driver ensures that the pendulum continues on at the right velocity to keep the appropriate period.

Comment: BenCrowell: Yes, but in this case, the force is applied continuously, as the pendulum always reaches the same height on every swing.
KyleCanos: Yes, but how to conserve those parameters without affecting the rotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At any given moment, the pendulum is swinging in a certain plane. The driving force should be within this plane. If the earth weren't rotating, then such a force could never cause the plane of swing to rotate about a vertical axis, since by symmetry there would be no preferred direction for the rotation.

Comment: And indeed the drive circuits typically take advantage of the broken symmetry of the situation to insure this. Example: http://www.google.com/patents/US3424960